# Mongoose: Cannot overwrite model once compiled on vercel

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, vercel

In my `server.js`:

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        email: { type: String, required: [true, "Email is required"] },
        password: { type: String, required: [true, "Password is required"] },
        phone: { type: String },
        orderhistory: [String],
        paymentinfo: {
            cardnumber: { type: String },
            CCV: { type: String },
            cardexpiry: { type: String },
        },
        listeditems: [String],
    },
    { collection: "Users" }
);
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

This code runs fine on `localhost` but when I deploy to Vercel I get an error:

```
Connected to MongoDB database
OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `User` model once compiled.
    at Mongoose.model (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/mongoose.js:563:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/server.js:38:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1356:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1414:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1197:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:12)
    at exports.b (/var/task/___vc/__launcher/chunk-5UAC7W5H.js:1:1142)
    at /var/task/___vc/__launcher/bridge-server-BGIDXK2J.js:1:1443
    at Function.Re (/var/task/___vc/__launcher/bridge-server-BGIDXK2J.js:1:1809)
    at e.<computed>.L._load (/var/task/___vc/__launcher/bridge-server-BGIDXK2J.js:1:1413)
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 1593.75 ms   Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
```

This is the only place I have defined a `User` schema.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by moving the `User` schema into its own route and importing it.

In `user.js`:

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema(
    {
        email: { type: String, required: [true, "Email is required"] },
        password: { type: String, required: [true, "Password is required"] },
        phone: { type: String },
        orderhistory: [String],
        paymentinfo: {
            cardnumber: { type: String },
            CCV: { type: String },
            cardexpiry: { type: String },
        },
        listeditems: [String],
    },
    { collection: "Users" }
);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

and in `server.js`, add `var User = require("./user.js");`